# How to send HTML email on new registration in DRUPAL 6?

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-6

In Drupal, I want to send HTML email after registration. I have downloaded HTML MAIL module. How can I proceed?

Comment: Check the documentation, it's a basic feature. Look for actions and triggers.

Comment: and also we have specific StackExchange site for the Drupal question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ it could be helpful for you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the HTML Mail module unless you're sending some seriously fancy mail.

Go to /admin/user/settings

Check "Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account"

There should be boxes below to make a template.

Comment: Actually I want all Join Us url and facebook, twitter icon and associated links in registration mail. We can only use specific variables !username, !site, !password, !uri, !uri_brief, !mailto, !date, !login_uri, !edit_uri, !login_url. Do have any idea how to add image icons and join us hyperlink in registration email?

Comment: @DrupalNewbie: Please create a new question for that.

Comment: So you want a full blown HTML email. Then you WILL have to use the HTML Email module. As in the comments, read the module's documentation. The admin pages you will use are admin/settings/mailsystem and admin/settings/htmlmail

Comment: can you please tell me steps ?